# Prioritize messages in disruptor

Tags: disruptor-pattern

Generally the events in my disruptor need to be handle sequentially. However, we sometimes receive high priority events which needs to be prioritize to be handled first. Is there such a functionality in Disruptor (like a priority queue in Java?)